# how to select max value from database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have database with different value

number_reg

10

9

15

18

I tried

```
    sql = "SELECT * from table where number_reg=(SELECT max(number_reg)from table)"
    cmd = New OdbcCommand(sql, conn)
    dtreader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dtreader.Read Then
        textbox1.Text = dtreader.Item("number_reg") 
    Else
        textbox1.Text = "0"
    End If
```

but the output is 10 how to get output is 18 ??

Comment: Do you want to just retrieve the max of number_reg or do you want to retrieve all the record relative to this max value?

Comment: what datatype is `number_reg` in the database?

Comment: @ Plutonix datatype is verchart

Comment: @Steve i want just retrieve

Comment: `MAX` will not work right on text, you need to use numerics, longs, ints etc.  "9" will always evaluate greater than "100" in a text comparison. `Varchar` is text/string and simply not a number.   And Steve is asking *what* you wish to retrieve.

Comment: @plutox thank you for explan i've changed the datatype.. sory for my bad english.. im from indonesia :)

Comment: there might well be something else wrong because with that data, the return should have been "9" not "10".  What database is this that you are using ODBC?